# Java Lottery Class

Tags: java, arrays

So I am writing a `Lottery` class and class that demonstrates the `Lottery` class. I have the work done and it compiles, but when I run it I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4  
at LotteryDemo.main(LotteryDemo.java:21)
```

Here is what I have for the code, any help would be much appreciated!

**The `Lottery` class:**

```
    import java.util.Random;


import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Lottery
   {


  int NUM_DIGITS = 5;   
  int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[4];




  public Lottery(){
     Random rand = new Random();
     lotteryNumbers[0] = rand.nextInt(10);
     lotteryNumbers[1] = rand.nextInt(10);
     lotteryNumbers[2] = rand.nextInt(10);
     lotteryNumbers[3] = rand.nextInt(10);
     lotteryNumbers[4] = rand.nextInt(10);
     getLotteryNums();

  }


  public int numIntsInCommon(int[] picks){
     int inCommon = 0;

     for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
     {
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
        {
           if (lotteryNumbers[counter] == picks[index])
              inCommon++;
           return inCommon;
        }
        return inCommon;
     }

     return inCommon;
  }

  public String getLotteryNums(){
     return lotteryNumbers[0] + ", " + lotteryNumbers[1] + ", " + 
                    lotteryNumbers[2] + ", " + lotteryNumbers[3] + ", " +
                    lotteryNumbers[4];
  }




}
```

**The `LotteryDemo` Class:**

```
    import java.util.*;


   public class LotteryDemo
   {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int[] userNumbers = new int[4];

     System.out.println("Please supply your lottery picks. Choose unique numbers between 0 and 9.");
     System.out.print("Enter digit 1: ");
        userNumbers[0] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter digit 2: ");
        userNumbers[1] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter digit 3: ");
        userNumbers[2] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter digit 4: ");
        userNumbers[3] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter digit 5: ");
        userNumbers[4] = input.nextInt();


    Lottery lottery = new Lottery();


    System.out.print("Lottery Numbers: " + lottery.getLotteryNums());
  System.out.print("Number of matching digits: " + lottery.numIntsInCommon(userNumbers));
    if(lottery.numIntsInCommon(userNumbers) == 5)
        System.out.print("All 5 match! You have hit the jackpot!");
  }


}
```

Comment: Checking Stacktrace gives the line number.. where exception has occurred

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[4];
```

This means the array has 4 elements or `lotteryNumbers[0]` .... `lotteryNumbers[3]`

Thus `lotteryNumbers[4] = rand.nextInt(10);` will cause the above exception.

Similarly with `userNumbers` in main which is causing the exception.

```
int[] userNumbers = new int[4];
...
userNumbers[4] = input.nextInt(); // java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Answer (score 0):

You allocate your array with `new int[4]` which means it has 4 elements numbered 0 to 3.
When you access the element with index 4 it is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java have instantiation as follows:

```
type[] name = new type[size]
                       ^
```

The size represents the *number of indexes* in an array. As you know, arrays start at zero, thus:

```
int[] userNumbers = new int[4]
```

makes an array of:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
 0  1  2  3
```

`userNumbers[4]` therefore does not exist. You need to create `userNumber[5]` for five indexes.